# assigning dropdown list values in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, drop-down-menu

Here is my JSP.

```
<form:form action="changeSrtOrdrRecoveryAccount.do" id="sortOvrlyFrm" autocomplete="off">
          <c:if test="${not empty recoveryAccts}">
              <ng:dep-datatable stretch="true" xstyle="border:0">
                <ng:dep-datatable-tr xstyle="border:0;background-color:#FFFFFF;">
                  <ng:dep-datatable-th xstyle="border:0"><fmt:message key="label.rcvyAcct"/></ng:dep-datatable-th>
                  <ng:dep-datatable-th xstyle="border:0">Sort Order</ng:dep-datatable-th>
                 </ng:dep-datatable-tr>
                  <c:forEach items="${recoveryAccts }" var="recAcct">
                       <ng:dep-datatable-tr xstyle="border:0">
                           <ng:dep-datatable-cell xclass="borderlessTableCell">
                              <input type="text" name="recAcct" value="<c:out value="${recAcct}"/>" readonly="readonly" />
                           </ng:dep-datatable-cell>
                           <ng:dep-datatable-cell xclass="borderlessTableCell">
                              <select name="srtOption">
                                <option value="<c:out value="${recAcct}-0"/>">0</option>
                                <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${total}" step="1" varStatus ="status">
                                    <option value="<c:out value="${recAcct}"/>-<c:out value="${i}"/>"><c:out value="${i}"/></option>
                                </c:forEach>
                              </select>
                           </ng:dep-datatable-cell>
                       </ng:dep-datatable-tr>
                  </c:forEach>

                 </ng:dep-datatable> 
          </c:if>
       </form:form>
```

Here is my generated code.I am looking for a way to assign and display value of 1 for the srtOption for the 1st account and value of 2 for the 2nd account.With the current code, 0 is beind displayed in the srtOption dropdown lists for both accounts.If i add selected like in the following
then the value for both accounts displayed in the dropdowns is 2.

```
<option selected value="<c:out value="${recAcct}"/>-<c:out value="${i}"/>"><c:out value="${i}"/></option>
```

q

```
 <table   style="border:0" class="wt-ng-dt-dep wt-ng-dt-dep-stretch" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr  style="border:0;background-color:#FFFFFF;" class="wt-ng-dt-dep-tr wt-ng-dt-dep-tr-header">
                  <th  style="border:0" class="wt-ng-dt-dep-th">Recovery Account</th>
                  <th  style="border:0" class="wt-ng-dt-dep-th">Sort Order</th>
                 </tr>

                       <tr  style="border:0" class="wt-ng-dt-dep-tr">
                           <td  class="borderlessTableCell wt-ng-dt-dep-cell wt-ng-dt-dep-cell-first">
                              <input type="text" name="recAcct" value="1234567891234      - 1" readonly="readonly" />
                           </td>
                           <td  class="borderlessTableCell wt-ng-dt-dep-cell wt-ng-dt-dep-cell-first">
                              <select name="srtOption">
                                <option value="1234567891234      - 1-0">0</option>

                                    <option selected value="1234567891234      - 1-1">1</option>

                                    <option selected value="1234567891234      - 1-2">2</option>

                              </select>
                           </td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr  style="border:0" class="wt-ng-dt-dep-tr">
                           <td  class="borderlessTableCell wt-ng-dt-dep-cell">
                              <input type="text" name="recAcct" value="9876543219876      - 2" readonly="readonly" />
                           </td>
                           <td  class="borderlessTableCell wt-ng-dt-dep-cell">
                              <select name="srtOption">
                                <option value="9876543219876      - 2-0">0</option>

                                    <option selected value="9876543219876      - 2-1">1</option>

                                    <option selected value="9876543219876      - 2-2">2</option>

                              </select>
                           </td>
                       </tr>


                 </table>
```

Thank you guys for any help with this

Answer (score 0):

you are using two select with the same name, they should be unique, so that you can use the name to extract the value. 
If you add the option selected to the option, then its value will be selected, so you can't use both.
Better use a "cinclude" statement inside the option field to match to the value you want it to be, so it would be chosen as selected.

what you need to do is as follows:

```
<select name="srtOption">
 <option value="0">9876543219876      - 2-0</option>
 <option value="1">9876543219876      - 2-1</option>
 <option value="2">9876543219876      - 2-2</option>
</select>
```